# Launch an application at startup in C#

Tags: c#, startup

i have developed an application in C# and it works well. But my customer want it to start with the OS (in startup time).
so pleas advise me how can i do that.

Comment: Which OS does this relate to? There's more than one OS where the C# language is used.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy your application as window service. This service can be configured to start with OS boot.

Comment: thank u @Rahul Garg  but how can i do that . Is there a code for example?

Comment: You can use window service template in visual studio. For reference, follow the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer